# Error: Method invocation is not a constant expression on ElevatedButton.styleFrom

Tags: flutter, dart

So, I was just checking out the Buttons docs and trying to create an elevated button, a very basic thing and I followed the guide [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/buttons) to create a basic elevated button. But now I am getting an error on line `final ButtonStyle elevatedButtonStyle = ElevatedButton.styleFrom(` which is a bit weird cuz I am just following the guide.

Following is the error I get :

```
Error (Xcode): lib/login.dart:8:58: Error: Method invocation is not a constant expression.

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.
```

Below is my full dart file as you might see I just started making changes to it,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:samples/constants/constants.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {

  const LoginPage() : super();

  final ButtonStyle elevatedButtonStyle = ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    onPrimary: Constants.jaffaOrange,
    primary: Constants.jaffaOrange,
    shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(2))
    )
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            style: elevatedButtonStyle,
            onPressed: () { },
            child: Text('Login'),
          ),
        ),
     );
  }
}
```

I have a feeling I am making a stupid mistake (Been off dart and flutter for a while!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `const` from the constructor as `elevatedButtonStyle` is initialized with a non-constant value.

```
class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {

  LoginPage() : super();

  final ButtonStyle elevatedButtonStyle = ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    onPrimary: Constants.jaffaOrange,
    primary: Constants.jaffaOrange,
    shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(2))
    )
  );
...
}
```

Comment: Your answer is valid just doesn't apply to me so I am marking it as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up marking my style as static since I needed that const constructor

My final solution looks like:

```
final ButtonStyle elevatedButtonStyle = ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    onPrimary: Constants.jaffaOrange,
    primary: Constants.jaffaOrange,
    shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(2))
    )
  );
```